# Why does this RewriteRule cause an Internal Server Error?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I call my site this way locally:

```
http://localhost:80/mysite/de/layer1/layer2/module
```

In .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^((css|js|images)/.*)$ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L, NE]
```

I try to rewrite that into:

```
http://localhost:80/mysite/index.php/de/layer1/layer2/module
```

Any idea what's wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I can see is that the path should be mysite/index.php

Probably also have to remove the \mysite\ from your regex because as it is now your REQUEST_URI is going to include mysite\xxxxx

You should probably use a rewrite condition to skip css,images, etc and then rewrite like this

```
RewriteRule (.*) /mysite/index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is throwing errors at you, you should look in the server log to see why.  You can also enable logging of RewriteRule processing, see [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).